# Itextsharp Header spacing with multiple column

Tags: c#, itext, multiple-columns

I have created pdf file with itextsharp and I create Header ok but when I create table with two column. I don't have spacing from Header to my two column

[image: Images itextsharp]

The code

```
PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);
table1.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
table1.WidthPercentage = 100;

PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph UniName = new Paragraph(@"TRƯỜNG ĐẠI HỌC CÔNG NGHỆ ĐỒNG NAI", fontBold);
UniName.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(@"PHÒNG ĐÀO TẠO", times);
paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell11.AddElement(UniName);
cell11.AddElement(paragraph);
cell11.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE;

PdfPCell cell12 = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph QH1 = new Paragraph(@"CỘNG HÒA XÃ HỘI CHỦ NGHĨA VIỆT NAM", fontBold);
QH1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
Paragraph QH = new Paragraph(@"Độc lập - Tự do - Hạnh phúc", fontBold);
QH.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
Paragraph Symbol = new Paragraph(@"----------oOo----------", fontBold);
Symbol.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell12.AddElement(QH1);
cell12.AddElement(QH);
cell12.AddElement(Symbol);
cell12.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
table1.AddCell(cell11);
table1.AddCell(cell12);

Paragraph TitleReport = new Paragraph(@"TỔNG HỢP COI CHẤM THI", titleFont);
TitleReport.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

Paragraph Info = new Paragraph(string.Format(@"Từ ngày: {0}     đến ngày: {1}        Đơn vị: {2}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "Trung tâm quản lý chất lượng"), normalFont);

Info.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
Info.SpacingBefore = 20;
Info.SpacingAfter = 200;
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
int side_of_the_page = 0;
ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
int paragraphs = 0;
while (paragraphs < 28)
{
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
    table.AddCell("STT");
    table.AddCell("Số Phách");
    table.AddCell("Điểm bằng số");
    table.AddCell("Điểm bằng chữ");
    table.AddCell("Ghi chú");

    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        table.AddCell((i + 1).ToString());
        table.AddCell("209292");
        table.AddCell("4");
        table.AddCell("Điểm bằng chữ");
        table.AddCell("");
        ++paragraphs;
    }
    table.HeaderRows = 1;

    //table.LockedWidth = true;
    ct.AddElement(table);
    //ct.AddElement(new Paragraph(String.Format("Paragraph {0}: {1}", , TEXT)));
    while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
    {
        if (side_of_the_page == 0)
        {
            side_of_the_page = 1;
            canvas.MoveTo(297.5f, 36);
            canvas.LineTo(297.5f, 806);
            canvas.Stroke();
        }
        else
        {
            side_of_the_page = 0;
            doc.NewPage();

        }
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
    }
}

doc.Add(table1);
doc.Add(TitleReport);
doc.Add(Info);
```

*([Also here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ad2bf982a84342ae3b4d5ef527829c5))*

Comment: Please show the pivotal code.

Comment: My code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ad2bf982a84342ae3b4d5ef527829c5

Comment: As much as possible stack overflow questions should make sense without the need to consult external resources. Thus, I copied your code into your question.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't solve my problems. Please me if you can fix it

Comment: Ok, the cause of your issue is that you mix automatic layout by iText (when you add the document header and title using `doc.Add`) and manual layout (when you add the content table using a `ColumnText`). The automatic layout by iText does not take any content added by manual layout into account. Thus, you have to take the content added via automatic layout into account for your manual layout; probably it would be easier to use manual layout for everything. By the way, I'm a bit surprised that you add the document title *after* all the content. This can push your title onto a later page.

Comment: How can I fix it. Because I do it for about 2 hours and I try do like http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/columntext-examples/objects-columns

Comment: One question, do you need the header (`table1`, `TitleReport`, `Info`) on every page or only on the first page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that you mix automatic layout by iText (when you add the document header and title using `doc.Add`) and manual layout (when you add the content using a `ColumnText`).

The automatic layout by iText does not take any content added by manual layout into account. Thus, *you* have to take the content added via automatic layout into account for your manual layout (probably it would even be easier to use manual layout for everything).

Furthermore it is a bit surprising that you add the document title *after* all the content. Given enough content this pushes your title onto a page beyond the first!

And your `while (paragraphs < 28)` does not make any sense as in the first run through the `while` body you immediately push that variable beyond 28 in the inner loop `for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++) { ...; ++paragraphs; }`.

As in your code you add the header (`table1`, `TitleReport`, `Info`) only once, I assume you want to use this header on the first page only.

I changed your code by:

- adding the header to the `Document` first,
- requesting the current **y** position from the `PdfWriter`,

  ```
  float afterHeaderY = writer.GetVerticalPosition(true);
  ```

  assuming the `PdfWriter` being named `writer`,
- using this **y** position as the top **y** coordinate of the columns and the center line on the first page reverting to the hard coded 806 on later pages, and
- removing the `while` loop and code in comments.

The new code:

```
PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);
table1.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
table1.WidthPercentage = 100;

PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph UniName = new Paragraph(@"TRƯỜNG ĐẠI HỌC CÔNG NGHỆ ĐỒNG NAI", fontBold);
UniName.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(@"PHÒNG ĐÀO TẠO", times);
paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell11.AddElement(UniName);
cell11.AddElement(paragraph);
cell11.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE;

PdfPCell cell12 = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph QH1 = new Paragraph(@"CỘNG HÒA XÃ HỘI CHỦ NGHĨA VIỆT NAM", fontBold);
QH1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
Paragraph QH = new Paragraph(@"Độc lập - Tự do - Hạnh phúc", fontBold);
QH.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
Paragraph Symbol = new Paragraph(@"----------oOo----------", fontBold);
Symbol.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell12.AddElement(QH1);
cell12.AddElement(QH);
cell12.AddElement(Symbol);
cell12.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
table1.AddCell(cell11);
table1.AddCell(cell12);

Paragraph TitleReport = new Paragraph(@"TỔNG HỢP COI CHẤM THI", titleFont);
TitleReport.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

Paragraph Info = new Paragraph(string.Format(@"Từ ngày: {0}     đến ngày: {1}        Đơn vị: {2}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "Trung tâm quản lý chất lượng"), normalFont);

Info.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
Info.SpacingBefore = 20;
Info.SpacingAfter = 200;

doc.Add(table1);
doc.Add(TitleReport);
doc.Add(Info);

float afterHeaderY = writer.GetVerticalPosition(true);

Rectangle[] COLUMNS = new Rectangle[] {
    new Rectangle(36, 36, 290, afterHeaderY),
    new Rectangle(305, 36, 559, afterHeaderY)
};

PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
int side_of_the_page = 0;
ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
table.AddCell("STT");
table.AddCell("Số Phách");
table.AddCell("Điểm bằng số");
table.AddCell("Điểm bằng chữ");
table.AddCell("Ghi chú");

for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
{
    table.AddCell((i + 1).ToString());
    table.AddCell("209292");
    table.AddCell("4");
    table.AddCell("Điểm bằng chữ");
    table.AddCell("");
}
table.HeaderRows = 1;

ct.AddElement(table);
while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
{
    if (side_of_the_page == 0)
    {
        side_of_the_page = 1;
        canvas.MoveTo(297.5f, 36);
        canvas.LineTo(297.5f, afterHeaderY);
        canvas.Stroke();
    }
    else
    {
        side_of_the_page = 0;
        doc.NewPage();

        COLUMNS = new Rectangle[] {
            new Rectangle(36, 36, 290, 806),
            new Rectangle(305, 36, 559, 806)
        };
        afterHeaderY = 806;
    }
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
}
```

The result:

[image: Screenshot]

The big gap between header and content is due to your setting

```
Info.SpacingAfter = 200;
```

If you don't want that gap, reduce the value accordingly.

Comment: @ChungPhạmBáTuấn Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer? Did you run into trouble using it?

Comment: No. I accepted your code. I remember I clicked to accept (V) but now I'm comeback I can't see this :(

Comment: @mkl Thank you so much for this, it's the only example of the entire web to create a 2 column layout with iTextSharp.